# Java Script to change Nav Bar text to image on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

Hi I have the following code for a website which currently displays the text "Prince Resourcing" in the Nav Bar. When the user scrolls, the colours of the Nav Bar change, but what I really want is to replace the "Prince Resourcing" text with a thumbnail image I have created. I can't seem to get it to work, can anyone help? Thanks.

creative.js code

```
 (function($) {
  "use strict"; // Start of use strict

  // Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing
  $('a.js-scroll-trigger[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 56)
        }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

  // Closes responsive menu when a scroll trigger link is clicked
  $('.js-scroll-trigger').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
  });

  // Activate scrollspy to add active class to navbar items on scroll
  $('body').scrollspy({
    target: '#mainNav',
    offset: 57
  });

  // Collapse Navbar
  var navbarCollapse = function() {
    if ($("#mainNav").offset().top > 100) {
      $("#mainNav").addClass("navbar-shrink");

    } else {
      $("#mainNav").removeClass("navbar-shrink");
    }
  };
  // Collapse now if page is not at top
  navbarCollapse();
  // Collapse the navbar when page is scrolled
  $(window).scroll(navbarCollapse);
```

index.html code

```
<body id="page-top">

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top" >Prince Resourcing</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Current Roles</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="index.html#blog">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="gdpr.html">GDPR</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="team.html">The Team</a>
          </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inline:

```
var navbarCollapse = function() {
    if ($("#mainNav").offset().top > 100) {
      $("#mainNav").addClass("navbar-shrink");
      $(".navbar-brand").html('<img src="/relative/path/to/image.png" />');
    } else {
      $("#mainNav").removeClass("navbar-shrink");
      $(".navbar-brand").html('Prince Resourcing');
    }
};
```

It would be preferential to use jQuery's `addCLass` however" `$(".navbar-brand").addClass("YourImageClass");`

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work.. even if I replace the line containing the image source with ` $(".navbar-brand").html('TEST');` the output does not seem to change. Any ideas?

Comment: This solution depends on what the **navbar-shrink** class is up to. Please post a snippet of the CSS that contains both  **navbar-shrink** and **navbar-brand**